# Entity Framework Core 3.1 - Creating a secure self-referencing one to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

So here is my issue...what I am trying to create is a self-referencing one to many relationship.

Basically here is my model.

```cs
    public class Category : Entity<Guid>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
        public Category ParentFk { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is my dbContext.

```cs
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(c => 
        {
             c.HasOne(b => b.ParentFk)
                              .WithMany()
                              .HasForeignKey(b => b.ParentId)
                              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });
     }
```

The question is what are you doing if you want to avoid cycle or self row referencing:

**SKIP**

1. Animals Category > Cats Category > Animals Category *--> no EF exception*
2. Animals Category > Animals Category *--> no EF exception*

Answer (score 0):

You need to code for it. For a start I recommend taking a DDD approach with restrictions on entity setters so that entities only expose methods for mutations which can help ensure validation occurs and an entity is always in a complete enough state. Self-referencing entities are a pain because they're essentially going to trigger lazy-loading scenarios to ensure that you don't introduce a loop. (For a given item, you need to iterate up the Parents until there is no loop)

For example:

```
public class Category : Entity<Guid>
{
    // ...
    
    public Guid? ParentId { get; internal set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Category ParentFk { get; internal set; }


    private bool referencesParent(Guid? parentId)
    {
        return (parentId.HasValue && ParentId.HasValue && Parent.referencesParent(parentId));
    }
    
    public void UpdateParent(Parent newParent)
    {
        if(newParent == null)
            Parent = null;

         var isValid = referencesParent(newParent.Id)
             && newParent.referencesParent(Id);
         if (isValid)
            Parent = newParent;
         else {} // Handle case where a cycle would be introduced. Exception? return result?
    }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that it will lazy load the current object's Parent and ancestors as well as the newly proposed parent object's ancestors to detect introducing a cycle. (this code: `&& Parent.referencesParent(parentId)`) Eager-loading optional cyclic references isn't a simple matter AFAIK.

The alternative would be to potentially compose a recursive SQL statement given the two IDs to search for a possible match. (resulting in 1 or 2 queries rather than an indeterminate # of lazy loads)

Answer (score 0):

This does not happen during construction, so no need restrictions on entity setters.

```cs
    protected async Task Create(CreateOrEditCategoryDto input)
    {
        var category = ObjectMapper.Map<Category>(input);

        await _categoryRepository.InsertAsync(category);
    }

    protected async Task Update(CreateOrEditCategoryDto input)
    {
        var category = await _categoryRepository.GetAsync((Guid)input.Id);

        if(input.ParentId.HasValue)
        {
            var parentCategory = await _categoryRepository.GetAsync((Guid)input.ParentId);

            while (parentCategory != null)
            {
                if (category.Id == parentCategory.Id)
                {
                    input.ParentId = null;
                    break;
                }

                parentCategory = await _categoryRepository.GetAsync((Guid)parentCategory.ParentId);
            }
        }

        ObjectMapper.Map(input, category);
    }
```

Here's my attempt and answered my question if we have -100 raw.